# How do preprocessors handle parenthetical parameters in macros?

Tags: objective-c, macros

I have a macro like this:

```
#define FBOX(x) [NSNumber numberWithFloat:x]
```

And I've heard that macros are handled by the preprocessors in such a way where source will just be replaced by the macro text, but that doesn't make sense to me when parentheses are thrown in the mix because I never actually say `FBOX(x)`. I say something like `FBOX(1.0f)`. So how *exactly* does the preprocessor handle parameters in macros?

Comment: What's the confusion? What you say is correct. `FBOX(1.0f)` is translated to `[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f]`

Comment: BTW - such a macro is obsolete these days. Use the new literal boxing syntax. Example: `[someArray addObject:@1.0];` or `[someArray addObject:@(somePrimitiveNumberTypeVariable)];`.

Comment: @rmaddy NSNumber can hold `BOOL` too.  Does `@YES` and `@NO` work?  Or should I be using `@1` and `@0`?

Comment: @nhgrif Yes, `@YES` and `@NO` are valid and basically replace `NSNumber numberWithBool:`.

Answer (score 2):

> So how exactly does the preprocessor handle parameters in macros?

*Essentially* macro replacement is *string replacement*, but it is *language aware*.

The *language aware* part is that the replacement text of the macro and the macro's parameters must be whole tokens in (Objective-)C(++); you can't include, say, an opening double-quote without a closing one. However this awareness stops at the level of tokens, you can define macros, and pass macro arguments, which are incomplete chunks of code, or even invalid chunks of code - as long as the individual tokens are valid.

As part of the language awareness, comments and extra whitespace is also removed during preprocessing.

The *string replacement* part is that the macro "call" is replaced simply by the text (the individual tokens) that make up its definition, and each use of a parameter in the definition is replaced by the text of the parameter in the call. This all happens *before* the compiler analyzes the syntax of the code.

So in your example:

```
#define FBOX(x) [NSNumber numberWithFloat:x]
```

then the "call":

```
... FBOX(1.0f) ...
```

is replaced by:

```
... [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f] ...
```

before the compiler analyzes the syntax of your code.

To see that the macro is being tokenised, we can redefine your macro as:

```
#define FBOX(x) [NSNumber numberWithFloat:x.0f]
```

and then try:

```
... FBOX(1) ...
```

The macro is replaced successfully, but then the compiler produces an error when analyzing the syntax because the result text looks like:

... [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1 .0f] ...

where `1` & `.0f` are *two* tokens and not a single floating point number. The compiler therefore expects a `]` after the `1` and will report an error.

In Xcode if you select Product:Perform Action:Preprocess Code Xcode will show you the result of your file after preprocessing.

Answer (score 0):

It simply replaces `x` with `1.0f`, so:

```
NSNumber *n = FBOX(1.0f);
```

becomes:

```
NSNumber *n = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f];
```

this is then presented to the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
#define FBOX(x) [NSNumber numberWithFloat:x]
```

Using `FBOX(1.0f)` will be replaced by:

```
[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f]
```

---

In a way, it's similar to writing a method...

```
- (void)foo:(NSObject*)bar {
    // do stuff with bar
}
```

You're not necessarily passing a variable named `bar` into the method.  You're just passing in a variable.  The body of the method then uses the variable for whatever the method does, it's just that when you write it, you refer to it as `bar` because you have to have some sort of name for it.